# C++ pointer "losing" its value

Tags: c++, pointers

As an exercise (largely an exercise in trying to write something using pointers), I'm writing a cache simulation, specifically of the pseudo least recently used system from the old 486. I'm getting an "Access violation reading location" error on the line:

```
int min = treeArray[set]->root->findPLRU();
```

Initially the treeArray seems to be initialised properly (if I pause the program at the start and take a look, it's all as should be), but when the programme breaks and I delve in to examine things the root of the tree in question isn't defined.

I feel it's quite probable that I'm making some sort of very elementary pointer mistake, which is causing the pointer to the node to be "lost" somewhere, but I've no clue what it might be. Is there something in particular I need to do to "hold on" to a pointer value?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h>

#include "main.h"

//char fn[80];                              // trace filename
int tf;                                     // trace file
trace buf[BUFSZ / sizeof(trace)];           // buffer SIZE
int LRUHits = 0;
int pLRUHits = 0;
int randomHits = 0;
int height;

int cachelinenumber;



//log2 helper function
int log2(int n)
{
int i = 0;
while (n)
{
    n = n >> 1;
    i++;
}
return i - 1;
}

class CacheLine{
public:
int tag;
int access;
CacheLine();
};

class Cache;

class Node{
public:
bool goRight;
Node* left;
Node* right;
int leftCacheLine;
int rightCacheLine;

Node(int depth) // constructor
{
    goRight = false;
    if (depth < height - 1)
    {
        left = new Node(depth + 1);
        right = new Node(depth + 1);
        leftCacheLine = -1;
        rightCacheLine = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        leftCacheLine = cachelinenumber;
        cachelinenumber++;
        rightCacheLine = cachelinenumber;
        cachelinenumber++;
    }
    //printf("Depth: %d, Height: %d, Left: %d, Right: %d\n", depth, height, leftCacheLine, rightCacheLine);
}

~Node()
{
    delete left;
    delete right;
}

int findPLRU()
{
    if (leftCacheLine < 0 || rightCacheLine < 0)
    {
        if (goRight)
        {
            goRight = false;
            return right->findPLRU();
        }
        else
        {
            goRight = true;
            return left->findPLRU();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (goRight)
        {
            goRight = false;
            return rightCacheLine;
        }
        else
        {
            goRight = true;
            return leftCacheLine;
        }
    }
}
};

class Tree{
public:
Node* root;
Tree()
{
    root = new Node(0);
}

~Tree()
{
    delete root;
}

};

//cache class
class Cache
{
public:
CacheLine *cache;

int l, k, n, replacementPolicy;
int log2l, log2n;
int access;
Tree** treeArray;
//constructor
Cache(int ll, int kk, int nn, int _replacementPolicy)
{
    l = ll;
    k = kk;
    n = nn;
    replacementPolicy = _replacementPolicy;
    log2l = log2(l);
    log2n = log2(n);

    cache = (CacheLine*)malloc(sizeof(CacheLine)*k*n);

    for (int i = 0; i < k*n; i++)
    {
        cache[i].tag = 0x80000000;
        cache[i].access = 0;
    }

    if (replacementPolicy == 1)
    {
        cachelinenumber = 0;
        treeArray = new Tree*[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            treeArray[i] = new Tree();
        }
    }
    access = -1;
}

//destructor
~Cache()
{
    free(cache);
}



//test for hit
void hit(int a) 
{
    access++;

    int set = (a >> log2l) & (n - 1);
    int tag = a >> (log2n + log2l);

    CacheLine* c = &cache[set*k];

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        if (c[i].tag == tag)
        {
            c[i].access = access;
            if (replacementPolicy == 0)
                LRUHits++;
            else if (replacementPolicy == 1)
                pLRUHits++;
            else if (replacementPolicy == 2)
                randomHits++;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (replacementPolicy == 0) //LRU
    {
        int min = 0; 
        int minv = c[0].access;
        for (int i = 1; i < k; i++)
        {
            if (c[i].access < minv)
            {
                minv = c[i].access;
                min = i;
            }
        }
        c[min].tag = tag;
        c[min].access = access;
    }
    else if(replacementPolicy == 1) // pseudoLRU
    {
        int min = treeArray[set]->root->findPLRU();
        c[min].tag = tag;
        c[min].access = access;
    }
    else // random
    {
        srand(clock());
        int randomNumber = rand()%k;
        c[randomNumber].tag = tag;
        c[randomNumber].access = access;
    }
    return;
}
};

void analyse (int l, int k, int n)
{
height = log2(k) + 1;
char fn[] = "ico0.trace";
if ((tf = open(fn, _O_RDONLY | _O_BINARY )) == -1) {
    printf("unable to open file %s\n", fn);
    exit(0);
}

LRUHits = 0;
pLRUHits = 0;
randomHits = 0;
Cache *cache0 = new Cache(l, k, n, 0); // LRU
Cache *cache1 = new Cache(l, k, n, 1); // pseudoLRU
Cache *cache2 = new Cache(l, k, n, 2); // random

int bytes, word0, a, type, burstcount;
int hits = 0;
int tcount = 0;

while (bytes = read(tf, buf, sizeof(buf)))
{
    for (int i = 0; i <  bytes / (int) sizeof(trace); i++, tcount++) 
    {
        word0 = buf[i].word0;
        a = (word0 & ADDRESSMASK) << 2;
        type = (word0 >> TYPESHIFT) & TYPEMASK;
        burstcount = ((word0 >> BURSTSHIFT) & BURSTMASK) + 1;
        cache0->hit(a);
        cache1->hit(a);
        cache2->hit(a);
    }
}
printf("Hits: %d  Total: %d\n", LRUHits, tcount);
printf("Hits: %d  Total: %d\n", pLRUHits, tcount);
printf("Hits: %d  Total: %d\n\n\n", randomHits, tcount);
delete cache0;
delete cache1;
delete cache2;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
//analyse(16, 1, 8);
analyse(16, 2, 512);
//analyse(16, 4, 256);
//analyse(16, 8, 128);
//analyse(16, 1024, 1);
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't compile: http://ideone.com/qCewp

Comment: Apologies. I'd only included the specific function where the problem was - but of course, that's not really enough to go on. Sorry! (full code there now)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question hasn't yet been pounced upon, probably because your code still doesn't compile since you've not provided `main.h`.

And even then it would annoy most folks trying to help you because you make no mention of the `ico0.trace` file that is required to prevent the code from immediately exiting.

You say `int min = treeArray[set]->root->findPLRU();` access violates.

1) the value of `set` can never exceed the size `n` of your `treeArray` since you `& n-1` the range of input values.

2) since your `~Tree()` destructor is *never* called there will always be a `treeArray[set]->root`

3) since you *always create new `left` & `right` nodes whenever `leftCacheLine = -1` or `rightCacheLine = -1` it cannot be due to recursive `findPLRU`s

So, the pointer to the node is *not* being "lost" somewhere; it is being stomped on.

Try replacing:

```
    int min = treeArray[set]->root->findPLRU();
    c[min].tag = tag;
    c[min].access = access;
```

with:

```
    int min = treeArray[set]->root->findPLRU();
    if (min >= k*n)
    {
        printf("ook\n");
    }
    else
    {
        c[min].tag = tag;
        c[min].access = access;
    }
```

and I think you will discover what's doing the stomping. ;)

Comment: Apologies, and apologies again. You're absolutely right, I've framed this question in such a way as to be basically unanswerable. And yet you've still somehow managed to get close enough to an answer to help drag me out of the apparently mindless hours I'd spent trying to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for making the effort to solve this, despite the non-compiling sample.

Comment: @Fraser ~ noP. i just live for mad challenges; like making sand-castles just before hi-tide... rotffl